# How to Authenticate to MySQL with PHP using SSL Certificates

Tags: php, mysql, ssl, openssl

I'm trying to authenticate to my MySQL Database (MySQL Server 8.0 in Windows Server 2019) using self-signed SSL Certificates created with OpenSSL. I have followed several tutorials that explain how to create these certificates and configure MySQL to use them, and it appears to be working. For instance, when I execute the command:

```
mysql.exe -u user-with-ssl -p --ssl-mode=REQUIRED
```

The user is successfully logged in, although I'm not entirely sure how the system knows where the client certificate is located to allow the login.
Now, I want to achieve the same authentication using PHP. I have also attempted various methods, but none of them seem to work. Below, I will provide a few examples along with the corresponding error messages I encounter when running them:

```
$db = mysqli_init();
mysqli_options ($db, MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT, true);

$db->ssl_set('C:\certs\client-key.pem', 'C:\certs\client-cert.pem', 'C:\certs\ca-cert.pem', NULL, NULL);
$link = mysqli_real_connect ($db, 'localhost', 'user-with-ssl', 'sslpassword', 'database', 3306, NULL, MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL);
if (!$link)
{
    die ('Connect error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . '): ' . mysqli_connect_error() . "\n");
} else {
    $res = $db->query('SHOW TABLES;');
    print_r ($res);
    $db->close();
}
```

Returns the error: "Error: Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:0A000086:SSL routines::certificate verify failed in"

```
$pdo = new PDO(
    'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database',
    'user-with-ssl',
    'sslpassword',
    array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY => 'C:\certs\client-key.pem',
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT => 'C:\certs\client-cert.pem',
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => 'C:\certs\ca-cert.pem',
    )
);
```

Return the error: "Uncaught PDOException: PDO::__construct(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:0A000086:SSL routines::certificate verify failed in ... Next PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] (trying to connect via (null))"

```
$pdo = new PDO(
    'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database',
    'user-with-ssl',
    'sslpassword',
    array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY => 'C:\certs\client-key.pem',
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT => 'C:\certs\client-cert.pem',
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => 'C:\certs\ca-cert.pem',
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => false,
    )
);
```

Returns the error: "Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: PDO::__construct(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:0A000418:SSL routines::tlsv1 alert unknown ca in ... Next PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away in ..."

I will also leave here the my.ini configuration file:

```
[mysqld]
ssl-ca     = "C:\certs\ca-cert.pem"
ssl-cert   = "C:\certs\\server-cert.pem"
ssl-key    = "C:\certs\\server-key.pem"
```

And the tutorial this code is based on: https://fedingo.com/how-to-enable-ssl-for-mysql-in-windows/

Does anyone know what could be causing this issue?
Thank you!

Comment: You shouldn't ask "How to Authenticate to MySQL with PHP". Because it will be a duplicated question. Besides, from your code it is evident that you already know how to do that. Your problem is some error and you should ask about specifically about this error

Comment: Unless authentication for `user-with-ssl`  requires X509 validation (subject, issuer) there is no need to specify client certificates.